# Does every Sylow Subgroup have same cardinality?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I know that the result is clear if group is finite. But what if the group is infinite?

Comment: No, for example $S_3$ has Sylow subgroups of orders 2 and 3.

Comment: Or, if you want Sylow $p$-subgroups for the same prime $p$, $S_3$ has a Sylow subgroup of order $2$ and $S_4$ has a Sylow subgroup of order $8$.

Comment: Oh come on Derek, you know exactly what is meant: same prime in the same group.

Comment: @NickyHekster  I don't think it should be left to the reader to try and guess what the poster means. If an exam question was worded like that, then I would expect the answers in my comments to be given full marks. (But I did upvote your answer.)

Comment: Of course you are absolutely right about a crisp and sharp formulation. But considering the fact that this person just joined...

Answer (score 7):

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be arbitrary finite $p$-groups, and let $G=P_1*P_2$, be their free product. Then $P_1, P_2 \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$(=by definition the set of *maximal $p$-subgroups*), and hence in an infinite group Sylow $p$-subgroups can have different cardinalities and so, need not to be conjugate.

The proof is not entirely trivial and uses the [Kurosh Subgroup Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem). See also D.J.S. Robinson, *A Course in the Theory of Groups*, Theorem 14.3.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. If you deem my answer as the right one, please tick it as such.